# How to get a list of locked accounts / check that account is locked?

Tags: oracle

I can use following statement to unlock an account:

```
ALTER USER username ACCOUNT UNLOCK
```

But which statement can I use to verify that account is currently locked out?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As [Dba's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/52642/30273) already shows, account status information is accessible via the `dba_users` view. Connected with a user having the appropriate grants, this can also be used to identify "inactive users":

```
SELECT username, account_status, created, lock_date, expiry_date
  FROM dba_users
 WHERE account_status != 'OPEN';
```

tells you for each locked/expired account when it was created, which state it is in (locked, expired, expired and locked, expired(grace)), and what time it was locked or expired. Useful for a "cleanup"; but you should consider that some accounts might just be "data holders" which are never connected to for security reasons, but required either by Oracle itself or your application(s). A good example for those is the system account `OUTLN`. So take care to only "clean out" accounts you know are not used/needed :)

Answer (score 6):

Use `DBA_USERS` View.

```
SELECT username, account_status
FROM dba_users;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can query this by specifying the username also:

```
select username, account_status
from dba_users
where username = 'your_user_name';
```